# Arrangement of $4$ pieces on a chess board

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Q. What is the total number of ways in which **four** distinguishable pieces be placed on an $8$X$8$ chess board such that no two pieces are in the same row or column?

This question is remarkably similar to the question in which there are **eight** pieces, but this case is different, as both cannot be solved by the same method.

If there were eight pieces, the number of ways would have been simply $(8!)^2$. That could be thought as one piece per each row, with the piece in the first row having $8$ possible places, the second having $7$ and so on, giving
$$ 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot2 \cdot1 = 8!$$ for each row. Multiplying the $8!$ cases for each column, we get $(8!)^2$

I am not able to think of any helpful approach to the four piece case.

How can the four piece case be solved?

Comment: As the answers point out, your answer for eight pieces is not correct.  It should be $(8!)^2$ and you can use the same technique to get there.

Comment: @RossMillikan I did not notice the mistake. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: I have added it to the question now.

Answer (score 5):

Let's put a piece on one of the $64$ squares on your chessboard. Now you have eliminated one row and one column, so you are left with a $7\cdot7$ chessboard. You can put your piece in one of that $49$ squares. For the third one, as you can imagine, you'll have a $6\cdot6$ square and so on.

So, in total, you have $8^2\cdot7^2\cdot6^2\cdot5^2$ possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

The first piece has $64$ possible locations to choose from, the second has $64-15=49$, the third has $49-13=36$, and the fourth has $36-11=25$

So the total number is $$64\times 49\times 36\times 25 = 2822400$$

Answer (score 1):

You can put piece $1$ on any of the 64 squares. You then come to piece $2$.
It must be in a different row and column to piece $1$. How many possible
square are there for piece $2$? piece $3$? piece $4$?

Comment: Is the answer $8^2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 6^2 \cdot 5^2$?

Comment: @AnanthKamath Aha!

Comment: Aha indeed! Thanks, @Lord Shark the Unknown!